# Insert and sort string in a Linked List

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to insert a string node in a linked list and sort it. The issue I'm having is with the line `while((curr != null) && (str > curr.Data))`. I am getting the error "operator < cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'". I don't understand this error as the function works fine with == and it also works in the case that they're ints and not strings. I've tried using `str.CompareTo(currData)` but that generates a similar error. If someone could explain to me **why** this error is generating and possibly what I can do to get around it that would be great.

```
private Node head = null; // initially nothing in the list
    private int count = 0;

    public void InsertSorted(string str)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(str);
        Node previous = null;
        Node curr = head;

        while((curr != null) && (str > curr.Data))
        {
            previous = curr;
            curr = curr.Next;
        }
        if(previous == null)
        {
            newNode.Next = curr;
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode.Next = curr;
            previous.Next = newNode;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
while((curr != null) && (string.Compare(str, curr.Data) > 0))
```

The `>` operator isn't valid for strings in C#.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that was the case. Thank you so much; this solved my error.

Comment: I don't have to do string comparisons often. I probably would have tried > or < first myself.